# enum passing multiple field values?

Tags: java, enums

I've been starting to read about `enum`s, and a wrote a small test class just to try it out:

```
public enum EnumTest{
  ITEMONE ("The 1st option"),
  ITEMTWO ("The 2nd option"),
  ITEMTHREE ("The 3rd option");

  EnumTest(String s){
    System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```

It should print "The 1st option" when I set it to `ITEMONE`, "The 2nd option" when I set it to `ITEMTWO`, etc., right?  Instead, it's printing all of them:

```
EnumTest e = EnumTest.ITEMONE;
```

prints

```
The 1st option
The 2nd option
The 3rd option
```

What's going on?

Comment: Enum instanes are all built when the JVM is initialized; that is why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enums are created statically once the class is loaded. Since the `print` statement is inside the constructor, you will see all messages printed, because all enum constants are created.

If you want to see only one specific message, you could try it like this:

```
public enum EnumTest{
    ITEMONE ("The 1st option"),
    ITEMTWO ("The 2nd option"),
    ITEMTHREE ("The 3rd option");

    private final String message;

    EnumTest(String s){
        this.message = s;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
}
```

and then in your `main`:

`System.out.println(EnumTest.ITEMONE.getMessage());`

or alternatively

```
EnumTest e = EnumTest.ITEMONE;
System.out.println(e.getMessage());
```

Answer (score 1):

The enum creates all its values at load time. So when you first use it, all three values are created - hence the three messages.

Note that you can achieve the same result just loading the class (`Class.forName()`).

EDIT. If you want to only print one value, don't do it in the constructor.

```
public enum EnumTest{
  ITEMONE ("The 1st option"),
  ITEMTWO ("The 2nd option"),
  ITEMTHREE ("The 3rd option");

  private final String string;

  EnumTest(String s){
    string = s;
  }

  public String getString() {
    return string;
  }
}
```

Comment: So how would I make it print just one, like it's supposed to?